# liquibase 3.4.1 and doesn't work with Java 7

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to switch from liquibase depedencies from 3.0.2 to 3.4.1 in a Java based tool but when running with Java 7 (tried different updates including latest 80) i'm getting strange exceptions like:

> 2015-11-13T11:55:43,351+02:00 ERROR  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find generators for database class liquibase.database.core.MSSQLDatabase, statement: liquibase.statement.core.UpdateStatement@5232d51 - [pool-3-thread-1]
>   liquibase.exception.LockException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find generators for database class liquibase.database.core.MSSQLDatabase, statement: liquibase.statement.core.UpdateStatement@5232d51

or

> iquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find unique implementation of liquibase.executor.Executor.  Found 0 implementations
>       at liquibase.executor.ExecutorService.getExecutor(ExecutorService.java:31) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.1.jar:na]

With Java 8 everything works fine.

Is this a known issue? Is there any documentation stating 3.4.1 works only with Java 8 (couldn't find anything).

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: 3.4.1 works fine for me with Java7

Comment: Hi Mark, can you tell me the exact Java 7 update you are using ? Thanks, Dan

Comment: My name's not Mark, but I can tell you the version nevertheless: build 1.7.0_55-b13 on Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're experiencing the issue fixed in [this bug report](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2700).  If you upgrade to 3.5.x you should be okay.